# Spatial Join Point within Polygon Python

Tags: polygon, point, geopandas, geoprocessing

My final project is to improve Waze with AI.
In order to do that I need to join 2 datasets.

1 - jams - linestrings that I convert to polygons using buffer

2 - alerts by user - points

Both are in the same city.

After cleaning the data and make columns as geometry object
I need to add to alerts DF new column with value of the jams that contain the alert. I tried a lot of solutions in the net, no one helped me.

This is the 2 dataset: [Alerts + Traffic](https://file.io/yOzwECMtiQnR)

screenshot head -
[image]

```
Trafficjan.set_geometry("polygeo")

m = gpd.sjoin(Alertsjan, Trafficjan, how="left", predicate="within")
```

This code gives me nothing.

Answer (score 0):

set_geometry is not in place, it is returning a data frame. So you are not changing anything with your code.

```
import geopandas as gpd

road = gpd.read_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/small_road_sample.shp")
alert = gpd.read_file(r"/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/small_road_sample_randpoints.shp")

road["buffer"] = road.buffer(1000) #Create a column with buffered lines/polygons

road.set_geometry("buffer") #This does not set the geometry in place, it is returning a dataframe
# road.geometry
# 0      LINESTRING (674867.662 7175384.128, 674813.154...
# 1      LINESTRING (681203.816 7174459.938, 681064.945...

road["oldgeom"] = road.geometry #Save the line geometries to be
# able to able to go back to them after the join

road = road.set_geometry("buffer") #Then do this to set the polygons as geometries

# road.geometry
# 0      POLYGON ((674105.219 7173524.585, 674083.449 7...
# 1      POLYGON ((680835.875 7171500.973, 680640.249 7...

alerts_within = gpd.sjoin(left_df=alert, right_df=road, how="left", predicate="within")
# alerts_within
#     id_left  ...                                            oldgeom
# 0       0.0  ...  LINESTRING (665662.375 7166913.539, 665534.059...
# 0       0.0  ...  LINESTRING (666183.436 7168040.957, 666178.778...
# 0       0.0  ...  LINESTRING (665662.375 7166913.539, 666121.528...
# 1       1.0  ...                                               None
```

Another option is to use [sjoin_within](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.sjoin_nearest.html).